# Binding application settings to a control gives errors

Tags: vb.net, binding, application-settings

As soon as I try and assign Application settings - Property binding to a control in my application I get the following error:

> Access of shared member, constant member, enum member or nested type
>   through an instance; qualifying expression will not be evaluated.

My form design view then errors out with a stack trace error:

> at System.Windows.Forms.ControlBindingsCollection.AddCore(Binding
>   dataBinding) at System.Windows.Forms.BindingsCollection.Add(Binding
>   binding) at System.Windows.Forms.ControlBindingsCollection.Add(Binding
>   binding)

And I also get warnings (or messages) popup saying:

> Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: dataBinding

I get this error for every control I try and bind to my application settings.  My application will still run fine though.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Just an update that I have noticed for every control that I have binded application settings to, I get the following warnings in the Designer.vb page: The type 'DrakeMon.My.MySettingsProperty' has not property named 'Settings'.

Comment: Your application setting are **shared** and binding expects to be bound to a property within an instance of a class. If it works, and you are OK with ignoring the warning, then continue on. Otherwise I would create a class with your properties in it, create an instance at run-time and fill in the properties with your application settings.  I'm sure there is another way, this is just 1 way off the top of my head.